# What is the difference between tf-nightly and tensorflow in PyPI?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, tensorflow2.0, pypi

What is the difference between `tf-nightly` and `tensorflow` in PyPI?

```
pip install tf-nightly
pip install tensorflow
```

Which one is reliable?

https://pypi.org/project/tf-nightly/

https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just to add to [what Ben Souchet wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59500388/17242583):

1. As its name suggests, the `tf-nightly` pip package is built and released to [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/tf-nightly/) every night (barring any build failures, which happens rarely). As a result, you can see an [almost once-per-day version update history](https://pypi.org/project/tf-nightly/#history). It has the latest features close to the HEAD of the master branch of [github.com/tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow). Therefore, if you want the latest features, improvements and bug fixes, such as the ones committed after the last stable `tensorflow` release (see below), you should use `pip install tf-nightly`. But the downside is that because `tf-nightly` releases are not subject to the same strict set of release testing as `tensorflow`, it'll occasionally include bugs that will be fixed later. Also, since it's built from HEAD, it'll reflect intermediate developments status such as incompleteness in features.
2. The `tensorflow` pip package is released by a semantic-version-based schedule. A new version is pushed out approximately once 2-6 months. Due to the comprehensive set of release testing jobs, the quality is higher than `tf-nightly`. The documentation on https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/ is updated once per minor version bump in the `tensorflow` pip package.

Answer (score 6):

The Nightly is used to get earlier access to the latest tensorflow development ideas, this version is daily updated. It's the same as with browsers ([see here](https://www.askvg.com/what-are-chrome-canary-firefox-nightly-and-opera-developer-versions/)).

> Which one is reliable?

The classic tensorflow `pip install tensorflow` is the most reliable of the two. this version has been tested by lot of people before being released.