# AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'model'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning, keras-layer

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

def build_dqn(lr, n_actions, input_dims, fc1_dims, fc2_dims):
    model = Sequential([
        Dense(fc1_dims, input_shape=(input_dims,)),
        Activation('relu'),
        Dense(fc2_dims),
        Activation('relu'),
        Dense(n_actions)])

    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=lr), loss='mse')

    return model
```

I am trying to understand Double Deep Q-Learning. There is a pretty good lecture here: https://github.com/philtabor/Youtube-Code-Repository/tree/master/ReinforcementLearning/DeepQLearning

But when I tried to run the code, I got following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/panda/PycharmProjects/ddqn/main.py", line 33, in <module>
    ddqn_agent.learn()
  File "/home/panda/PycharmProjects/ddqn/ddqn_keras.py", line 118, in learn
    self.update_network_parameters()
  File "/home/panda/PycharmProjects/ddqn/ddqn_keras.py", line 121, in update_network_parameters
    self.q_target.model.set_weights(self.q_eval.model.get_weights())
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'model'
```

And I have no clue on how to fix this. I guess keras has been updated to not allow this?

The different lines are respectively:

**line 33:**

```
ddqn_agent.learn()
```

**line 118 (in `def learn(self):`):**

```
self.update_network_parameters()
```

**line 121 (in `def update_network_parameters(self):`):**

```
self.q_target.model.set_weights(self.q_eval.model.get_weights())
```

**line 76:**

```
self.q_target = build_dqn(alpha, n_actions, input_dims, 256, 256)
```

**EDIT:** updated the problem based on suggestions in the comment section. The suggestion was that I put a `tensforflow.` in front of keras in the imports. I get the same error as before (as you can see). Here is how the imports look like now:

[image]

Comment: Before any `keras` adding `tensorflow` like: `from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation       from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
        from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam`

Comment: You can also use `Sequential` without `models` like : `import tensorflow as tf` next line: `tf.keras.Sequential([....])`

Comment: @I'mahdi thanks, I tried it, it didn't work. Anyway, when I type tensorflow.keras.layers the keras-part of the line is marked with red in PyCharm. I don't know, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: add new full code and new error with editing your question

Comment: @I'mahdi thank you, I have updated this post with your suggestions.

Comment: @I'mahdi any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I need to see the full code. where do you crate ddqn_agent and ddqn_agent.learn() and ...

Comment: The full code is here: https://github.com/philtabor/Youtube-Code-Repository/tree/master/ReinforcementLearning/DeepQLearning ... the entire code consists of the files dqqn_keras.py, main_keras_ddqn_lunar_lander.py and utils.py.

The only thing I have changed is what you suggested (tensorflow.keras instead of keras).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solving your error you can go through the below steps:

**1. Install dependency for can run the `env`:**

```
!pip install https://github.com/pybox2d/pybox2d/archive/refs/tags/2.3.10.tar.gz
!pip install box2d-py
!pip install gym[all]
!pip install gym[box2d]
```

**2. Change imports like below:**

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras import Sequential
from keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
```

**3. Install `tf-nightly`:** *([what is tf-nightly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59502169/1740577))*

```
!pip install tf-nightly
```

Comment: thank you so much, I am truly grateful <3

Comment: Didn't work in my case...

Comment: @Caterina, you can ask your question with your problem and state that you got an error, maybe me or other people can help you.

Comment: Isn't model attribute deprecated now? This is what I read so I wasn't able to find a solution.

Comment: @Caterina, I Edited the answer, I checked the answer on [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/). You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70323949/1740577) also. After installing restart runtime and if got an error run again `!pip`s. You can see this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z81jh.png)

Comment: I tried that again and I have same error. The line raising the error is: if isinstance(model, Sequential):  self.model = model.model and the error is: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'model'

Comment: I created a new post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74941909/sequential-object-has-no-attribute-model